# Simple php program doesn't work

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Roll Em!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Roll Em!</h1>
    <?php
    $roll = rand(1,6);
    print "You rolled a $roll";
    print "<br>";
    ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

It is quite simple program, but for some reason doent work!
And it gives output like this

```
 Roll Em!

"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error is the space between `<?` and `php`, but the full code should be:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Roll Em!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Roll Em!</h1>
    <?php
    $roll = rand(1,6);
    echo "You rolled a " . $roll;
    echo "<br>";
    ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

You shouldn't use print, echo is better in nearly all cases, and you should use " . $string . " to paste a variable into a text string.

Comment: Well i replaces php tag but it sill doesn't work. The output is the same. Even with the eco function.

Comment: Make sure you copy the whole code I wrote here - I just tested it on my own server and it works perfectly

Comment: Also, are you sure the file extension is .php and not .html?

Comment: Oh, thanks that might be the reason

Comment: Did it work when you changed it?

Answer (score 2):

PHP start tag should be:  `<?php` - without space.